# Numpy installation gets stuck on ec2 micro instance

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-ec2, pip

Trying to install `numpy==1.9.2`. Was able to install it smoothly on my local machine. While trying to install on a micro instance it gets stuck infinitely in the following state.

```
$pip install numpy==1.9.2
DEPRECATION: --download-cache has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Pip now automatically uses and configures its cache.
Collecting numpy==1.9.2
Using cached numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz
Running from numpy source directory.
Installing collected packages: numpy
Running setup.py install for numpy
```

I have installed all possible dependencies for numpy, so I am sure it can't be a dependency issue.

Is it something related to memory limitations of the micro instance?

**EDIT**

I upgraded my pip version to `6.0.8` from `1.x` before trying to install `numpy`. Dunno if that is causing troubles.

Comment: Could it be your ssh freezing rather than the installation failing? If so try installing from a screen session (start or reconnect with `screen -dRR`, exit session with `ctrl+a` then `d`)

Comment: ah, would try and let you know the results. Thanks for the help.